# SQL command not inserting all values in datagrid into db,

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to pass gridview data into database. The problem I am having is that not all data in my gridview is entering the database. Doing a messagebox shows only name column is going in. Here is my code

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sc As StringCollection = New StringCollection
    Dim field1 As String = String.Empty
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < GridView1.Rows.Count)
        field1 = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
        i = (i + 1)
    Loop
    ' get the  field to be Inserted
    sc.Add(field1)
    ' add the field to be Inserted in the StringCollection
    InsertRecords(sc)
    ' call method for insert and pass the StringCollection values

End Sub





Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=****************;Database=******;Uid=*******;Pwd=****;allow user variables=true")
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(String.Empty)
    For Each item As String In sc
        Const sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO student(name, age, adress) VALUES ("
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}'{1}' ", sqlStatement, item)

    Next
    sb.Append(")")

    MsgBox(sb.ToString)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sb.ToString, conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        Dim msg As String = "Insert Error:"
        msg = (msg + ex.Message)
        Throw New Exception(msg)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to create a sql command but use parameters.

Comment: Could you please show example

Comment: What is `sc` and where's your code which executes the command?

Comment: Tim I have just updated my code

Comment: Yes, but again, what is `sc`?

Comment: Yes i know, but it's not clear how you get the name, age, adress from one string. Therefore my answer assumes that it's a custom class with all properties, just to show the principle.

Comment: Sorry Tim I don't know if it will make a difference but I've included the button click event code if that is what you were indirectly referring to.

Comment: Is it ASP.NET or Winforms? If the former, can you show the aspx of rhe GridView? Which db-column is in which grid-column?

Comment: It is asp.net but with the gridview I upload an excel spreadsheet using  a file open system. Which then populates the gridview

Comment: So do you know which column in the grid maps to which column in the table or not? However, have you understood my code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't concatenate strings to create a sql command but use parameters to primarily avoid sql-injection.

```
Const sqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO student(name, age, adress) VALUES (?Pname,?Page,?Padress)"
Try
    Using con = New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        For Each item In sc
            Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlStatement, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Pname", item.Name)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Page", item.Page)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Padress", item.Padress)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    ' log message '
    Throw ' don't use throw new Exception or throw ex '
End Try
```

Note that i've used `sc` like a collection of a custom class with all needed properties. But even if that was not correct, it should give you an idea how it works.

Comment: @Steve: And i've forgotten to add my sql statement ;)

Comment: Thanks guys Im going to give that a go. Its really appreciated!!

Comment: The problem i now get is the Pname in the paramater section is not a member of a string

Comment: @user1712552: Then you should tell me what type it is. You can convert it, for example to int: `int.Parse(stringValue)` etc.

Comment: I dont understand . This is what im doing cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Pname", item.name) Now when I bang that in Im getting error there is a blue line under item.name. When hovering mouse over it is says 'name' is not a member of 'String'.

Comment: As i've mentioned in my answer(at the bottom) i've assumed that `sc` is a collection of objects(a custom type with all properties needed). Of course a string does not have a property `Name,Page` or `Padress`. But since i didn't know where i should get these values i've showed you that way and hoped that you would understand how to modify the code acordingly. I could show you the rest if i would know how your grid looks like.

Comment: I don't understand Tim. Im sorry this is taking a while I'm a complete noob. Ok the scenario is I have a gridview which is not bound. Its just the standard gridview I got dragged and dropped from the toolbox. I then made an upload button which when I click it uploads an excel sheet to the gridview. Now the gridview is dynamically changed. I then have a submit to database button. Which when the user clicks should submit what ever is in the gridview to the database.

Comment: Your table `student` has three columns: name, age, adress. 1. What type is each column in the datatabase? 2. How do you want to extract each column from the gridview? For example: Is name in the 4th column, adress in the 6th and age in the second? What kind of gridView columns do you use, BoundFields or TemplateFields with controls? That's the reason why i said that you should show me the GridView aspx-markup.

Comment: yes student has three columns. Each column is set as to Varchar. Column 1 is name, Column 2 is age and Column 3 is address. Here is the aspx                                                           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 3px; top: 3px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 187px">
             </asp:GridView>